# Twilio Flex is not displayed correctly inside Salesforce

Tags: flexbox, salesforce, twilio

I try to integrate Twilio Flex in Salesforce like this:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/admin-guide/integrations/salesforce#

However, the Flex application is not displayed correctly inside Salesforce: [image: Screenshot]

In addition, nothing pops up on an incoming call.

Has anyone a hint what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Saleforce Integration has not been enabled in the Flex Admin console. https://flex.twilio.com/admin/integrations